# Opennms add outage

Tags: opennms

I'm having a problem where adding an opennms scheduled outage is not functioning. Considering I can find limited documentation about how to do this through their interface (I suppose it's supposed to intuitive), I'd like to confirm these are the correct steps.

I begin by clicking on a node and clicking to "schedule outage" (Home / Admin / Scheduled Outages / Edit). I click a node and then on the main form page, I; search for a node and click "Add" (with or without "Add with path"), set "outage type" to "specific" and click "set", set a time between 2014 00:00:00 and 2014 23:59:59 (to set outage for all day) and click "add outage", then under "applies to" I select "all notifications" and scroll to the bottom and click "Save".

This will then redirect me to the scheduled outage log, of which I can see some entries but my entry that was just created does not appear and a scheduled outage is not set. Before I start looking into any potential server problems, can somebody please let me know if these steps are correct and not just user-error causing my problem?

Comment: What version of OpenNMS?

Comment: 1.12.5. Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be the right sequence... I just created a quick outage in my environment (*OpenNMS  1.10.8*).

If the new outage does not save, you may have a database or application issue not he OpenNMS side. Please provide the version of your installation. If there's an existing outage, try editing it and seeing if the settings stick. Otherwise, the logs or the OpenNMS mailing list are the best resources for your problem.

Before:
[image]

---

Outage selection interface:

[image]

---

Results:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Ok... so that actually works now. The only difference between your method and mine is that you clicked "Add new outage" from that main outage page, and I had originally went to an individual node page and clicked "schedule outage". They both redirect to the same page, but adding it through my original method seems to append a few arguments to the URI such as "newName=nodeName&addNew=true&nodeID=88. Interesting..